# Proving uniform continuity of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, absolute-value, uniform-continuity

Prove that the function $f(x) = |x-a| - |x-b|$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: given e>0 choose delta= such that whenever |x-y|<delta for all x and y in R |f(x)-f(y)|<||x-a|-|x-b|-|y-a|+|y-b||.

Comment: I do not know how to simplify the absolute value equation to show it is less than epsilon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x,x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, for some $\epsilon > 0$. If $|x-x_0| < \delta$, then
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(x_0)|&=|(|x-a|-|x-b|)-(|x_0-a|-|x_0-b|)| \\
&= ||x-a|-|x-b|-|x_0-a|+|x_0-b)| \\
&= |(|x-a|-|x_0-a|)-(|x-b|-|x_0-b|)| \\
&\le ||x-a|-|x_0-a||+||x-b|-|x_0-b|| &\text{Triangle Inequality} \\
&\le |(x-a)-(x_0-a)|+|(x-b)-(x_0-b)| &\text{Reverse Triangle Inequality} \\
&= |x-x_0-a+a|+|x-x_0-b+b|  \\
&=|x-x_0|+|x-x_0| \\
&=2|x-x_0| \\
&<2\delta \\
&=2\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
Thus, by definition, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq ||x-a|-|y-a||+||x-b|-|y-b||$.
- For every pair of real numbers $c$ and $d$ it is true that $||c|-|d||\leq |c-d|$.

Using this, you should be able to arrive at the expression $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2|x-y|$. This is sufficient to show that your function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: how did you get +|x-b|? How would I simplify the first part of the equation?